# Get visualforce page pdf blob in apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, blob

I have a visualforce page that renders as a pdf. Is there any way in apex to get that page data as a blob? I've thought about doing an Http GET request, but I feel like there should be a more direct way to get the page's blob data in my apex class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any of the [PageReference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_System_PageReference_methods.htm) methods. The most straightforward would be:

```
Blob pdfData = Page.myPageName.getContent();
```

Note that this technically still counts as a callout (meaning, you cannot use DML before calling it), but is far shorter than any other solution.

If this should be dynamic:

```
Blob pdfData = new PageReference('/apex/myPageName').getContent();
```

Comment: Wonderful, thanks!